Ubuntu 22 and 23 gray colors are turned white
I was using ubuntu 23.10 and after a simple Ubuntu update, the colors for gray tones was broken and now all gray tones looks like white as you can see in this screen shot from https://imagecolorpicker.com/color-code/ebebeb
I installed ubuntu 22 and the problem remains.
expected:

actual:

I'm using the recommended Nvidia driver 550 (tested, proprietary)
my PC is using an Nvidia rtx-3070 and this is the same driver I was using in the past, one weird thing is if I move another window over the color-code page, then the shadow projected by the other window shows the correct colors through the shadow

Seems like the issue was not in the gpu drivers, I solved it changing the option of my samsung monitor of "black level" to "normal", for some reason, this option I never touched, and ubuntu was working correctly, but for some reason after a software upgrade seems like this options is now causing this issue, I don't know way this happened, because this option is from the monitor itself and I never touched it, but the thing is this worked for me.
I don't know why in my windows partition everything is correct, and for ubuntu I have to change this monitor option, is weird.

My guess is that your monitor needs adjustment.
You can use this test image to test it.
http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/white.php
If that is your problem, trying adjusting the "contrast" control for your monitor.
You may also want to ensure your blacks are the correct level, for which you may use your "brightness" control.
If there is no adjustment that will fix there, there is a very unlikely alternative explanation: if your monitor is a TV, it may be incorrectly receiving full-range levels when it expects video levels (16-235) - a setting in the TV should correct this so that it can use full-range levels.

Thanks for the response, I have a windows partition which is using the same monitor and it shows colors correctly, so this makes me think is not related with the monitor itself, I tried removing completely ubuntu installing from scratch in a new partition but the issue is still there :(. is weird because I was using ubuntu as usually and after an upgrade of linux stuffs I got this color issue

What gpu drivers and what method of connection to the monitor from the gpu?  If nvidia proprietary drivers can you go to GPU -> (your display) -> color correction?
